# Merging XFDF or FDF file with a PDF into a single PDF programmatically via python

Tags: python, open-source, fdf

Requirement: Have a XFDF file with annotations and the original PDFfile. Need to Merge XFDF annotations into the PDF and save it using python libraries.

Is there any open source solution to achieve this without licensing?

I have used PDFTron with license and it works. But due to restrictions, do we have any other open source solutions?

Comment: Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. Questions asking us to find or recommend an off-site resource, like a library or tool, are explicitly _off-topic_ as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.